# Interpreting varImp using a GLMNET model on a 3-level factor

Tags: r, caret, glmnet

(tried stackoverflow but told I may have better luck here). I am looking for some help interpreting varImp using GLMNET multinomial model on a 3-level factor variable. The plot and the data don't make sense to me. Bin 1 shows var3 as most important, though it would seem that var1 & 2 do a better job. Bin 3 shows var3 as doing well over 50% and that doesn't make sense as var3 for bin 3 is completely random.

Also, should the 50% mark be considered neutral? or should it be 0%?

I love varImp's factor output, as long as I can reliably determine which variables are most important to which bin. What am I missing here?

[image]

Here is the data that I made up to illustrate my example (dput below):

```
var1,var2,var3,response
1,1,2,1
1,1,2,1
1,1,2,1
1,1,2,1
1,1,5,1
1,1,5,1
1,1,5,2
2,2,5,2
2,2,5,2
2,2,7,2
2,2,7,2
2,2,11,3 
2,2,12,3
2,2,23,3
2,3,24,3
3,2,112,3
3,3,12,3
3,3,18,3
3,3,12,3
3,3,20,3
3,3,2,3
3,3,3,3
3,3,4,3
```

Code to reproduce the following varImp chart:

```
library(caret)
data_file <- structure(list(var1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), var2 = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), var3 = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 11L, 12L, 23L, 24L, 112L, 12L, 18L, 12L, 20L, 
2L, 3L, 4L), response = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L)), .Names = c("var1", 
"var2", "var3", "response"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-23L))
predictors <- c("var1","var2","var3")
pretend_model <- train(
        x = data_file[,predictors],
        y= as.factor(data_file[['response']]),
      method = "glmnet",
      preProc = c("center", "scale"))

imp <- varImp(pretend_model, scale = T)
plot(imp)
```